# Fetching messages in the requested folder error

Tags: mailcore2

I've got an error when I updated the mailcore2 and used this method fetchMessageOperationWithFolder. The error is "An error occured while fetching messages in the requested folder."

Sorry I can't post any image yet!

Below is the result of my connection logger:

```
2014-11-19 15:16:52.531[485:45236] ERRORError Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=19 "An error occured while fetching messages in the requested folder." UserInfo=0x16788f80 {NSLocalizedDescription=An error occured while fetching messages in the requested folder.}
2014-11-19 15:16:52.545[485:45236] ()
2014-11-19 15:16:52.546[485:45236] INBOX
2014-11-19 15:16:52.547[485:45236] 9501
2014-11-19 15:16:54.110[485:45392] * OK Gimap ready for requests from 112.208.143.218 zq5mb132787189pbc

2014-11-19 15:16:54.122[485:45392] 1 CAPABILITY

2014-11-19 15:16:54.577[485:45392] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN

1 OK Thats all she wrote! zq5mb132787189pbc

2014-11-19 15:16:54.579[485:45392] 2 LOGIN "jcartas@village88.com" v31j10jer826

2014-11-19 15:16:55.318 [485:45392] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT

2 OK jcartas@village88.com authenticated (Success)

2014-11-19 15:16:55.320[485:45392] 3 COMPRESS DEFLATE

2014-11-19 15:16:55.934 [485:45392] 3 OK Success

2014-11-19 15:16:55.935 [485:45392] 4 ENABLE CONDSTORE

2014-11-19 15:16:56.547 [485:45392] * ENABLED CONDSTORE

4 OK Success

2014-11-19 15:16:56.549 [485:45392] 5 NAMESPACE

2014-11-19 15:16:57.264 [485:45392] * NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL

5 OK Success

2014-11-19 15:16:57.266 [485:45392] 6 ID NIL

2014-11-19 15:16:58.493 [485:45392] * ID ("name" "GImap" "vendor" "Google, Inc." "support-url" "http://support.google.com/mail" "version" "gmail_imap_141111.06_p1" "remote-host" "112.208.143.218")

6 OK Success

2014-11-19 15:16:58.495 [485:45392] 7 SELECT INBOX

2014-11-19 15:16:59.107 [485:45392] * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $NotPhishing)

* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $NotPhishing \*)] Flags permitted.

* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.

* 721 EXISTS

* 0 RECENT

* OK [UIDNEXT 868] Predicted next UID.

* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 83158]

7 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)

2014-11-19 15:16:59.109 [485:45392] 8 UID FETCH 9501 BODY.PEEK[]

2014-11-19 15:16:59.721 [485:45392] 8 OK Success
```

Comment: Please copy-paste your logs from connection logger.

Comment: Apparently, the message with UID 9501 doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure If that's the case, this is the process of our app:

1. Loading folder messages / emails (@INBOX)
2. Loading of content for each messages (one by one) / emails
3. When message / email body was not loaded the process above will be called. That's why I wonder if the message with UID 9501 doesn't exist!

Comment: For number 3, when the user view the email, and the content was not yet loaded, the process above will be called. Thanks!

Comment: The highest UID is lower than 868. Therefore, it's highly likely that 9501 doesn't exist.